Spring batch running processor/writer number of times as chunk size
In summary - if the spring batch recordset is less than the chunk size, shouldn't the processor/writer only run once, since the first chunk contains the entire recordset?

What looks wrong here is that you are operating on a list of entities. The correct code would be rather like:
public Step jobStep() {  
    return new StepBuilder("stepName", repo)  
            .<Entity, Entity> chunk(10, txnManager)  
            .reader(reader)  
            .processor(processor)  
            .writer(writer)  
            .build();  
}
public class JobProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Entity, Entity> {
    @Override
    public Entity process(Entity item) {
          //do some logic on one item
        return item;
    }
}

Similar for reader and writer classes not shown in your question.

As I explained you - this is how Spring Batch works. Check the interfaces ItemReader, ItemProcessor and ItemWriter. They all works with a single item. The items will be read, processed and written in chunks of the configured length. So don't worry about performance. Just implement the classes correctly.
